# Effect of $k$ on turning point?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

In the function $$y=(k-x)e^x ,$$

What is the effect of $k$ on the turning point of the function? I can't see any clear pattern when I change the variable.

**What are some real-life scenarios to which this relationship could be applied?**

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that a completely abstract function that you present without motivation, would necessarily have any direct applications?

Comment: I'm just curious, it seems like one of those situations where it is applicable somehow!

Answer (score 1):

I take it the "turning point" is the local maximum or minimum, which, by calculus, we know is where the derivative is zero. The derivative is $(k-x-1)e^x$. That's zero when $x=k-1$. So there's the effect on the turning point; it occurs at $k-1$.

Comment: Thanks! So does this have any practical applications? I mean, can you think of any scenarios where this would be used?

Comment: Could come in handy on a calculus test some time....

Comment: I mean I guess you're optimizing something, so it's showing you the x of the maximum value is equal to k-1, but can anyone think of any scenario problems where this would be applied?